# Label `split of ad' multiply defined

Tags: errors, warnings

I’m receiving the following warning in Line 1:
Label `split of ad` multiply defined.

I don't know what it means since in line 1 there is only 
`\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}`

Comment: Could you please provide an MWE (the smallest possible yet complete document that demonstrates the problem)?

Comment: it means that you have `\label{split of ad}` in two places. (the line 1 will refer to a file that is input, not your main file)

Comment: Thanks so much @DavidCarlisle that was precisely the problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that you have `\label{split of ad}` in two places. (The line 1 will refer to a file that is input, not your main file.)